# Prevent a large textbox from getting put on the second page in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formatting

Greetings.

I've got a large textbox in SSRS, with a few textboxes under it.  When I view the report in Preview mode, or from the Report Manager it looks fine.  But when I actually render it from code (into a PDF), it puts my large textbox on the second page (and leaves what's below on the first page).

There's a Connect request here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=238240

that details the problem, but it shows no workarounds.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason behind it breaking to the next page is probably because it's too long to fit on a page.  rs defaults a page to have 1 inch margins, so if you want it to print on a single page your report contents shouldn't be wider than 6 1/2 inches (8.5 inches minus 1 in for both sides).

you should be able to make the textbox have a smaller width and just give it a bigger height and it should print on one page.  also, changing the margins to 1/2in will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions, and I'm not sure which you've tried so I'll just list them:

- Is the text box growing too far to the right?  i.e. is the 2nd page a "right" page, or an actual second page?
- Is there anything you can do to the text box that gives you the desired result?  Have you tried making the box bigger by default, tried a smaller font size, removing the CanGrow property, etc?
- Is there anything else other than a textbox on the report?  Table/Matrix/etc have properties that will try to group them together or try to make them print on the same page

In the past when I've had similar problems with textboxes overflowing I have created an Expression to change the size of the font of the text box depending on the length of the content.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old, but according to [this](http://kelvinshen.blogspot.com/2012/05/prevent-large-textbox-from-getting-put.html) reference, you could always right click a textbox and change the `KeepTogether` property to false, which would  cleanly cut between a line and continue on the next page. This requires SSRS 2008 R2 and up.